# Which is the best option to send json using mvc4?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I would like to know which of these options is the best in order to return a json object using C#:

Option 1:

```
public EmptyResult GetImages() {
    /*operations*/
    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(images));
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

or option 2:

```
public EmptyResult GetImages() {
    /*operations*/
    return Json(images);
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever use the first approach?

Comment: How is this not answered with simple intuition?

Comment: Why post a comment if it's not constructive to the user's question? He's obviously not well-versed in MVC, or, to our knowledge, programming at all. Your comments are less intuitive than his initial solution.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is taking use of the great framework made just for these needs; WebAPI

Create an Api Controller

```
public class ApiTestController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Image> GetImages()
    {
        return yourDataAccess.GetAllImages()                            
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a little excessive, especially given that we don't know what else is going on in the rest of his implementation.

Comment: WebAPI is a lightweight framework, wcf rest would be excessive, but I disagree that a webapi controller would be. It's also a good practice to separate concerns, keeping controllers free of other than rendering views/partial views

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, it's definitely this:

```
public JsonResult GetImages() 
{
    //operations
    return Json(images);
}
```

Comment: But not with the EmptyResult. Be complete and post the full method.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was literally changing it while you typed that comment, hah